# Android build not considering proguard-rules

Tags: android, libgdx, obfuscation

In my LibGdx based android app I am using the build.gradle file with the progaurd files mentioned below. I have the progaurd-rules.pro file in the android project folder as shown  below.

**Question:**

1. I have released my apk in play store. Though I have progaurd-rules.pro,When my app crashed I do not get the line number of the file in which it had issue. Please let me know 2 things

   a. Do I need to copy the progaurd-rules.pro content to progaurd-project.txt ?

   b. Can I add the progaurd-rules.txt in android- build.gradle as mentioned in below code ?

   ```
   proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt', 'proguard-rules.pro'
   ```

2 . What is proguard-android.txt ,proguard-project.txt and proguard-rules.pro. Can I club proguard-project.txt and proguard-rules.pro ?

[image]

**android- build.gradle**

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
    }
}
```

**progaurd-rules.pro**

```
-keep class com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

**progaurd-project.txt**

```
-verbose

-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFragmentApplication
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxBuild
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.utils.Box2DBuild
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.jnigen.BuildTarget*
-dontwarn com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreetypeBuild

-keep class com.badlogic.gdx.controllers.android.AndroidControllers

-keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput* {

<init>(com.badlogic.gdx.Application, android.content.Context,    
java.lang.Object,        

com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration);
}

-keepclassmembers class com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World {
   boolean contactFilter(long, long);
   void    beginContact(long);
   void    endContact(long);
   void    preSolve(long, long);
   void    postSolve(long, long);
   boolean reportFixture(long);
   float   reportRayFixture(long, float, float, float, float, float);
}
```

**progaurd-android.txt**

```
com/google/firebase/provider/FirebaseInitProvider.class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the Play Store developer console to deobfuscate your stack traces, you need to upload the file `android\build\outputs\mapping\android\release\mapping.txt` to the *Android Vitals* -> *Deobfuscation files* section of your Application's menu in the console. This file will be newly generated every time you build your project, so you need to do this every time after you upload a new version of your app, and you must do it before you change any code and build again. Any existing stack traces will not get deobfuscated for you; only ones that are reported after you upload the mapping file. To manually deobfuscate the ones you already have, you can [use the retrace tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#decode-stack-trace), provided you haven't done another build since you uploaded the release version. Hopefully you're using version control, so that won't be a problem.

Note that above the second "`android`" might be something else, depending on how you have your `build.gradle` set up.

For your question 1, either your part (a) or part (b) are viable solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Proguard obfuscates your code by removing unused code and renaming classes, fields, and methods with semantically obscure names which make the code base, smaller and more efficient. The result is a smaller sized .apk file that is more difficult to reverse engineer. Proguard is integrated into Android build system.

When your app crashed if you want get the line number of the file in which it had issue. For this you need to integrate crashlytics like Fabric or any other available in market. I am giving an example of Fabric.

Add in your build.gradle

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }

  dependencies {
    // These docs use an open ended version so that our plugin
    // can be updated quickly in response to Android tooling updates

    // We recommend changing it to the latest version from our changelog:
    // https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


  compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
  }
```

Add your API Key in manifest file

```
 <meta-data
      android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
      android:value="<FABRIC_API_KEY>"
  />
```

Initialize your Kit in your MainActivity

```
 Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

Comment: I am not interested in other 3rd party libraries.. could you please help me without any new 3rd party libs but only with android developer console

Comment: That's ok. Could you please address my issue and the resolution for it